# How to show line number common to more files in emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex

I have a LaTeX project that consists of one master file and other files (mainly chapters) that are included in the main file via the `\input` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside,openany]{book}
....
\begin{document}
...
\mainmatter
\input{capitoli/one.tex}
\input{capitoli/two.tex}
\input{capitoli/n.tex}
...
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the included files usually lie in subfolders relative to the main file.

I would like that when I'm visiting, say, `two.tex` the line number shown at the bottom of the buffer by `line-number-mode` would not start from 1 but would consider the lines of code before that file (in this case the ones in the mail file and in `one.tex`). This is because when I compile the document with `pdfLaTeX` the compiler provides "general" line numbers for errors, so it's hard to find it in the source code. I tried the `linum mode`, but it seems to work just like the `line-number-mode` for the specific problem.

There is a way to achieve this behaviour?
I did not posted the question on [TeX.StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) because I think this is really an Emacs related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me latex reports the line number within a given file. How are you invoking latex that it gives "general" line numbers?

You should also consider using `-file-line-error-style` since that helps AUCTeX find the error in a few corner cases.  It causes errors to be printed like `./capitoli/three.tex:2: Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: Hitting C-c C-c RET Emacs uses: `pdflatex -synctex=-1 -src-specials "\input" "usr.tex"` (given the `synctex` option, this should be the default behaviour). Thanks for the other tip, but I usually compile in interactive mode, so the compiler stops automatically on the first error

Comment: Using that command I still get correct, i.e. local, line numbers and `TeX-next-error` has no problem finding the error.

Comment: After installing the new TeXLive 2012, everything is just as you say. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a hack to get what you're asking for, but you could use an (e.g.) `awk` script to prepare a file concatenating the `\input`'ed file into the file (see [this link](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7910)). From it, you can derive the offset of each file (the line number it has in the merged file). Then, you can use some form of relative line numbering (see e.g. [this link](http://overwatering.org/blog/2011/10/better-line-numbering-in-emacs/)). You then need some way of modifying your `.emacs` file whenever you open a `.tex` file that is not the main file (e.g. using an alias or a function).

With some work, you can get what you want, but it's not straightforward.

P.S. The line numbers from the concatenation might not be those reported on your error log, since there might be other macros expanding (e.g. `\include`).

Comment: This would be too tricky for me. I was searching for a more "out of the box" solution. Thanks